# Are questions related to Wordpress allowed?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/69286/add-new-button-in-appearance-panel-isnt-showing), but wasn't sure where to place it so I also posted at Wordpress Developers, where I removed the question after five minutes due to the fact that my question here was getting more attention.

A [moderator](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/20604/bybe) persistently claimed that the question is better off on Wordpress Developers, although it has nothing to do with Wordpress development or server configuration (as I host a different website with the same configuration on the same physical webserver which has the 'Add New' button).

As this website is a site for webmasters, one would think that this type of question would be allowed here.
Given a similar scenario of posting hardware questions on Stack Overflow, this would lead to a post deletion/closure as it would be off-topic.

From the FAQ:

> WordPress Stack Exchange is for WordPress developers and
> administrators to ask questions about:
>
> theme and plugin development development and management
>
> best practices
>
> server configuration for WordPress

My question wasn't about development, it was also not about best practices or server configuration, therefore it's off-topic for Wordpress Developers.
Are Wordpress-related questions on-topic here?

Further to this, the same moderator displayed ignorance of the site rules, and seemed to enforce every rule that he could try to find me breaking, even the 'no extended discussion' rule when I was repeatedly asking a user to stop commenting on my 'I have unlimited space' sentence in my question.

Comment: Would that really be off topic on the WordPress site?   It sounds like a configuration issue to me.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller It was a bug in the Wordpress installer. I resolved it by cleaning out my `public_www` directory, removing the MySQL database, and reinstalling Wordpress with the same settings as before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/181/ok-i-love-wordpress-as-much-as-the-next-guy-but-is-pro-webmasters-really-the-r?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Zyboxinternational,

I am sorry to hear that you believe that I was being ignorant as this was not my intention.  It may help if I explain why your question was considered off topic and what I believe more suited on the WordPress Stack.

*Webmasters is not a Umbrella term for everything administration*

It is often mistaken that Pro Webmasters is everything administration of a website, Webmasters is not a Umbrella term for everything administration or for questions that don't fit on another stack. In fact questions that go into depth regarding functions and options of a content management system unless related directly to web-mastering like seo are considered off topic. This applies to all CMS should it be Joomla, Drupal or WordPress.

*Migration*

Programming related questions generally get migrated to Stack Exchange while WordPress ones will be pushed to the WordPress Stack ***The important part***: If a moderator pushes a closed question to another network it doesn't necessary mean it complies with their rules either, generally moderators will check the rules before so, sometimes these rules are broad and open for speculation but ultimately the community members of that stack know what type of questions are allowed and what are not.